# Java - Make string not case sensitive

Tags: java, string

Here is a string

```
String foxes = "the,quick,brown,fox,jumped,over,the,lazy,dog";
```

I was wondering (although it is currently one in lower case)

What code would i use to make any string into Just lower or upper case

Many thanks

Comment: Look at the [API documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) of class `String` - there are methods there that do exactly what you want.

Answer (score 0):

What about the String toUpperCase() Method ?

```
String newString = foxes.toUpperCase()
```

See http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_touppercase.htm

Answer (score 0):

There's a method in the `String` class:

```
String foxes = "the,quick,brown,fox,jumped,over,the,lazy,dog";
String upperCase = foxes.toUpperCase();
String lowerCase = foxes.toLowerCase();
```

`String` is immutable, so you don't alter the original; you create new ones.